# Strange genre with fast beat and odd sound effects (Boomerang Lunchbox ad)

Tags: identify-this-genre, guitar

I am trying to find more music similar to that from [this old TV bumper.](https://youtu.be/GoZUEbibvVY)

The music in it is so weird I cannot explain what I am looking for. Something fast with a beat and strange sound effects?

I got nothing. Can someone help me identify this genre?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In its spirit, this music reminds me of Pierre Henry's music, the most famous piece being "Messe Pour Le Temps Présent":

If this is indeed what you are looking for, this is categorized in the [Musique Concrète](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musique_concr%C3%A8te) genre, even though Music Concrète is often not that fast and rhythmic (listen to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9on5gXqgQo&t=625s) for example).

Quoting Wikipedia:

> Musique concrète (French: [myzik kɔ̃kʁɛt]; lit. 'concrete music') is a type of music composition that utilizes recorded sounds as raw material. Sounds are often modified through the application of audio effects and tape manipulation techniques, and may be assembled into a form of montage. It can feature sounds derived from recordings of musical instruments, the human voice, and the natural environment as well as those created using synthesizers and computer-based digital signal processing.

You mention "strange sound effects". Again, quoting the same Wikipedia page:

> [Musique concrète] exploits acousmatic listening, meaning sound identities can often be intentionally obscured or appear unconnected to their source cause. (...) From the late 1960s onward, and particularly in France, the term [acousmatic music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acousmatic_music) (musique acousmatique) started to be used in reference to fixed media compositions that utilized both musique concrète based techniques and live sound spatialisation.

Indeed, searching for "[acousmatic music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acousmatic_music)" may lead you to similar music, like this one:

Comment: Thank you, I think Musique Concrète is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Great answer! I'd only add that "Plunderphonics" is a more modern descendant of the same idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plunderphonics  -- "Frontier Psychiatrist" is a good example of that genre. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLrnkK2YEcE

Comment: @ChrisSunamisupportsMonica I didn't know that music genre. I have to admit I pretty much like that particular song and I love the music video. Nice discovery, thank you!